# How do I set some row values using a vector with the same column names?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like a fast and efficient way to set the values in columns 'col_1' and 'col_2' in each row with an 'id' in ['b','c'] based on the values in another data frame. Below is a simple example of how I am trying to do this with df.update.

```
data = {'id': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
        'col_0': ['e','f','g','h'],
        'col_1': ['m','n','o','p'],
        'col_2': ['q','r','s','t']}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df

#the data frame dictating the changes to be made
cols=['col_1','col_2']
chg_dict={'b': ['b_0','b_1'],'c': ['c_0','c_1']}
chg_df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(chg_dict,orient='index',columns=cols)
chg_df

#make the change
for chg in chg_df.index:
    #mask to get index where id is in chg_dict
    mask=[r for r in df.index if df.loc[r,'id']==chg]
    #this is apparently where I go wrong, nothing changes
    df.loc[mask,cols].update(chg_df)
df
```

I have tried with and without the cols indexer.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i understand, you can try doing:

```
m=df.set_index('id')
m.update(chg_df)
df=m.reset_index()
print(df)

  id col_0 col_1 col_2
0  a     e     m     q
1  b     f   b_0   b_1
2  b     g   b_0   b_1
3  c     h   c_0   c_1
```

Comment: Yes, that does it! It was a long day and I confused pandas (which obviously can have duplicate indexes) and the other program I am using (which cannot). Thanks